# Running arduino sketch of c at arduino ide using java

Tags: java, eclipse, arduino-uno

I have Arduino code which is written in test.ino now I want to send it on Arduino ide using java. what should I do? my test.ino code is below.

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
}


void loop()
{
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);
  delay(1000);

}
```

Comment: It is pretty unclear where you have that file and what you want to do with it.

Comment: the file is in my java project. i just want the code of file in the arduino ide by a writing a script of java. means i dont want to open the file in arduino ide manually.

Comment: Dont understand a word op this.

Comment: i am sharing the link and i want the functionality of upload button in java.
http://blocklyduino.github.io/BlocklyDuino/blockly/apps/blocklyduino/

Answer (score 0):

In Arduino ide: Select the board type, Select the serial port to which your arduino is connected and hit the upload button (the one, that resembles right arrow).